# Is "what can I make of something?" grammatical?

Tags: phrase-usage

I gleaned a new phrase "what do you make of something" sometime ago(from a Australia TV show). I am wondering if I can say "what can I make of something". I have searched the google and yahoo, I can get several recommendations while entering "what do you make of" and "what do you make" but I can not while searching "what can you" or "what can I make" or "what can you make".

Is the saying "what can you/I make of something" natural to you?

Comment: Have a look at [make of](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/make_something_of), definition 1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

> What  can you/I make of something?

is grammatical.

Substituting the auxiliary  *can* for *do*  (and optionally changing the pronoun)  in *What do you make of it?* is acceptable in this case.

As for "natural," it is not necessarily something that a native speaker would say very often (which might explain the lack of results in your search).

When asking about the ability to derive some meaning out of something puzzling, a native speaker  is more likely to say

> Can you/I  make anything (out)  of it?

[Search results for "Can you make anything of it?](https://www.google.com/search?q="can+you+make+anything+of+it")

["Can you make anything out of it?](https://www.google.com/search?q="can+you+make+anything+out+of+it")

*Something* is possible instead of *anything* in the above.